# Table.buffer in power query - help me to understand this

Tags: function, powerbi, powerquery, m

I have been reading on a few articles on Table.buffer in the power query M function.

There have been a few sentences here and there that talks about "improving performance by keeping table in memory" or "loading on table and using this table to do other works instead of reloading the table again though the query steps..."

I understand a bit, but I am hoping for more of an metaphor or example if this possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's similar in principle to saving a function value that is expensive to compute as a constant when you'll be referencing it repeatedly further in your code. It can also be thought of as a [space-time trade-off](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%E2%80%93time_tradeoff), although increases in speed are not guaranteed.

What it does is load the table into memory so that it can operate on that stored in-memory cache rather than going back to the source data when applying further steps. Even though the M code is usually written in steps where one line is operating on the previous one as if it were being stored at each step, this is not actually what it's doing behind the scenes since it will automatically try to optimize doing things like query folding unless you specifically tell it not to with a `Table.Buffer` (which will break any query folding).